Calculating the resistance after a plunge cut laser trim
How do I calculate the resistance of this example resistor?
For this example I have a 100 by 100 units of resistive material that is 100 ohms per square and a perfectly uniform thickness.
If I make a laser cut starting 30 units in from the edge with a length of 30, what is the new resistance of the resistor?
Initially I had thought that the component became 3 resistors internally a 100 by 70, 70 by 30, and a 30 by 30 and that the resistance would be something like
$$
100\cdot \frac{100}{70}+100\cdot \frac{70}{30}+100\cdot \frac{30}{30} = 476.19
$$
But according to some of the reading I have done this does not appear to be the case.

Trimming Embedded Resistors
Resistor trimming geometry; past, present and future
ATP - LASER RESISTOR TRIM GUIDE

In those I learned about current crowding and how some squares end up only being calculated as 1/2 their value, but I am unsure how to calculate the are they in series, parallel or something completely different?


A Method can be used that is described in this paper:
Sandborn, P. and Sandborn, P. (2006), ''Using embedded resistor emulation and trimming to
demonstrate measurement methods and associated engineering model development''.
International journal of engineering education.

$$
R=R_{□}\left[\left(\frac{x_1+x_3}{D}\right)\:ln\left(\frac{W}{W-D}\right)+\frac{x_2}{W-D}\right]
$$
Substituting the values given in the OP example:
$$
R=100\left[\left(\frac{30+70}{30}\right)\:ln\left(\frac{100}{100-30}\right)+\frac{0}{100-30}\right]=118.89...
$$
The value can be estimated to be: 118.89
an increase of 18.89% from the starting value.

It's not a thing you calculate by hand, it's something you calculate with a Finite Element program. You could either use a publicly available one, or it's not that difficult to write your own as an exercise in programming.
It's fairly straightforward to get an upper and a lower bound by the sort of combinations of estimations of resistors you present in your question.
In practice, exact calculation is rather moot, as this is done as a trimming step, and the trimming proceeds until the measured resistance meets specification, no need for calculation at all.
There are some rather hairy mathematical ways to calculate this. I vaguely recall a mathematically clever engineer muttering things like Schwarz-Christoffel, and Wierstrasse, as he transformed a geometry not unlike the one you've shown into a more symmetrical arrangement that was ammeanable to an analytic solution.
The paragraphs you have read on 'current crowding' are rather important if this resistor needs any tolerance to power. The current crowding around the tip of the slot increases the power dissipation in that tiny region by a few orders of magnitude over the average for the whole resistor. What that means is that at apparently very low powers, the insulating slot can increase in length as the resistive material around the tip vapourises with the high power concentration. This can be mitigated by rounding the tip of the slot, reducing the current drowding.

You could use program such as COMSOL to get a more accurate answer, but I just banged down some resistors in LTspice and got more like a 15.5% increase for the cut you suggest:

With 1A flowing the voltage Vr is exactly 1V with the missing resistors in place. It's 1.155V with the shown 6 resistors removed.
You could easily plop down more resistors (maybe a 10,000 resistor array) so the exact position of the cut is less granular and the kerf width could be simulated. At some point LTspice will run out of resources, of course.
Regarding current crowding, the current through the resistor just above the cut (R6) is about 3x the current through the horizontal resistors when there is no cut (147mA vs. 50mA).
